# React : How To Map this Array and Display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

[image]

I have request that response with this object and I need to display it, but I don't how to deal with because the ( 61, 70, 81 and so on)

here is my code which is not working

```
{ events.events.map(event =>(
    <div key={event.ID}> 
     <p>{event.name} </p>
    </div>))
}
```

Comment: events is `object` not array, so you can't use `Array.map()` method.

Comment: @RahulKumar is there a way that I can convert this object to array ?

Comment: You can only use `map` on arrays not on object. You either need to use `Object.values`, `Object.entries` or if you only want keys then `Object.keys`.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed added the answer below,  can use `Object.entries()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` which will return array of `[key, value]` pairs.

Alternatively you can also use other methods like `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`. In below example I've used `Object.entries()` method.

```js
const events = {
  "events": {
    "61": {
      "ID": "61",
      "NAME": "test_name_61",
      "EVENT_DATE": "30.06.2021 12:03:00",
      "MIN_PRICE": 1000
    },
    "70": {
      "ID": "70",
      "NAME": "test_name_70",
      "EVENT_DATE": "30.06.2021 12:03:00",
      "MIN_PRICE": 1100
    },
    "81": {
      "ID": "81",
      "NAME": "test_name_81",
      "EVENT_DATE": "30.06.2021 12:03:00",
      "MIN_PRICE": 2000
    }
  }
};

Object.entries(events.events).map(([key, event]) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

> React.js code:

```
{ Object.entries(events.events).map(([key, event]) => (
    <div key={event.ID}> 
     <p>{event.NAME} </p>
    </div>))
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it as an object. So you can't use Array.map(). Instead you can use something like below

```
{ Object.values(events.events).map(event =>(
    <div key={event.ID}> 
     <p>{event.name} </p>
    </div>))
}
```

[Object.values(yourObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) gets you the values of all the keys in yourObject as an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
Object.values(events).map((eventValue) => console.log(eventValue))
```

to get values

```
Object.keys(events).map((key) => console.log(key))
```

to get key

```
Object.entries(events).map((event) => console.log(event))
```

to get event as array